# Regex that matches numbers, letters and dash but not the word net or NET

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

So far I have

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$
```

and it works great matching numbers, letters and dashes but now I want to exclude the word net in both upper and lower case.

More specifically,

**Match:**

net123

123net

word

etc...

**Don't Match:**

NET

net

how can I add that detail to the Regex?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by excluding the word? Skip the whole line if it's present?

Comment: In this situation I often test for a regex match for the words I don't want first (`m/[nN][eE][tT]/`). Then match if that test fails.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if the string is only net or only NET then don't match. but strings such as hello-net or net123 should be matches.

Comment: `^(?!NET$)[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$` with whatever case insensitivity flag your language provides? :)

Comment: Any reason not to do a more simple `if (testString.ToLower()!="net"` type logic rather than to roll it all into a single regex? it would be more readable at least but would depend what the context of its use is...

Comment: @Chris: it is the best approach if you don't want a specific character class

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to define the constraints in a route

Comment: @NicoTek: Yeah, I thought there might have been a reason you were constrained to needing a single RegEx but thought it worth bringing up (if nothing else for other people's benefit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?i)([\da-mo-z-]+|n+(?!et)|(?<=\d)net|net\d)+$
```

explanation:

`(?i)` case insensitive

`[\da-mo-z-]` character class without `n`

`|` OR

`n+(?!et)` n 1 or more time not followed by `et`

`(?<=\d)net` net preceded by a digit

`net\d` net and a digit

This pattern exclude strings that contains the word `net`, but if you want to exclude only strings that are the word `net`, you can do this:

```
^(?i)(?!net$)[a-z\d-]+$
```

Comment: It is a good approach but I want to allow strings such as 123NET

Comment: This doesn't match `net123`

Comment: This is a good answer. I forgot about the negative look ahead, and didn't even know about the inline options. The only thing it doesn't match that wasn't specified are variations of "Net" with upper and lowercase. If those were supposed to not match, then this is good. Otherwise you can change it to `^(?!net$|NET$)[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is the best approach, but you could do something like this:

```
@"^(?(net$|NET$) |[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$)"
```

Basically it is checking if the string is "net" or "NET", and if so, it matches it against a space. That will always fail. Otherwise, it does your normal match.

Here's a more detailed explanation.

First of all, it starts with a basic if statement and a start `^` anchor: `^(?(if)then|else)`

For the if statement, we check for "net" or `|` "NET". Each of these is in front of an end `$` anchor so that we know it is not a substring. Here's the result: `^(?(net$|NET$)then|else)`

Then if the statement is correct, I matched it against an space " ". Since we know the statement is already "net" or "NET", this part will always fail. That leaves us with this: `^(?(net$|NET$) |else)`

Finally, we plug in your previous pattern into the else clause to get: `^(?(net$|NET$) |[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$)`

After seeing the above answer, I remembered about negative lookaheads, which simplifys this by not needing a the dumb if statement. Using the lookahead, this answer would look like this:

```
@"^(?!net$|NET$)[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$"
```

Comment: I take back my comment and downvote. My error was testing the regular expression in a non .NET environment (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a negative lookahead assertion at the beginning like so:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"
    # Match word that is not NET
    ^              # Anchor to start of string.
    (?!net$)       # Assert that entire string is not NET.
    [0-9a-zA-Z-]+  # Match word.
    $              # Anchor to end of string.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // "Good" word that is not net, NET, Net,...
} else {
    // Not a "good" word.
}
```